# Insert label inside bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Is there a way to add hour/minute label to eonasdan's bootstrap datetimepicker like shown in the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: You'd probably have to tweak it yourself, but the maintainer would probably welcome the resulting PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ceejayoz stated in comments, the datetimepicker does not include this kind of functionality. The library is open source and you can customize the code and the look & feel as suggested.

Another appoach is to add dinamically a row under *hours and minutes* row when the picker is shown. You can add a listner to [`dp.show`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpshow) event and then use jQuery to manipulate picker HTML.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'HH:mm'
});

$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.show', function(){
  // Check timepicker is visible
  if( $('.timepicker').is(':visible') ){
    // Get rows of the timepicker
    var rows = $('.timepicker>.timepicker-picker>table>tbody>tr');
    // Create html for custom text
    var tr = '<tr class="customText"><td>hours</td><td class="separator"></td><td>minutes</td></tr>';
    // Add custom HTML inside component
    $(rows[1]).after(tr);
  }
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table tr.customText td {
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The datetimepicker has the [`debug`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#debug) option that, if set to `true`:

> Will cause the date picker to stay open after a `blur` event.

Comment: side question - how did you check the rendered HTML of the widget? Once the widget is expanded and you Right click -> Inspect Element with Firebug on the hour, the widget collapses and firebug HTML shows only the unexpanded widget HTML.

Comment: @joym8 I've edited my answer, to inspect the endered HTML of the component you can set [`debug`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#debug) option to `true`.